# OR operator not working in query sqlite iphone

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite

I am using Join operator to check two values in table but it does not work

```
select = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * FROM ContentMaster LEFT JOIN  Category  ON  ContentMaster.CategoryID= Category.CategoryID where ContentMaster.ContentTitle='%@' || ContentMaster.ContentTagText='%@' ",appDelegate.tagInput,appDelegate.tagInput];
```

If i do not use operator and use one in where clause then it shows result.

like

```
select = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * FROM ContentMaster LEFT JOIN  Category  ON  ContentMaster.CategoryID= Category.CategoryID where ContentMaster.ContentTitle='%@'",appDelegate.tagInput];


select = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * FROM ContentMaster LEFT JOIN  Category  ON  ContentMaster.CategoryID= Category.CategoryID where ContentMaster.ContentTagText='%@'",appDelegate.tagInput];
```

Any idea how to fix this issue so that or operator works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL (and SQLite in particular), operator `||` typically means string concatenation.

If you want logical `or`, use operator `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

In `sqlite` just use `or` for logical `or` operation:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ContentMaster 
LEFT JOIN  Category ON ContentMaster.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID 
WHERE ContentMaster.ContentTitle = '%@' OR ContentMaster.ContentTagText= '%@'
```